# JPA: Prevent cascade update in unidirectional onetomany mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a parent entity named QuestionPaper:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_paper")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class QuestionPaper {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "question_paper_id", columnDefinition = "INT")
    private int questionPaperId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_paper_id")
    @OrderBy("order")
    private Set<QuestionPaperCategory> questionPaperCategorys = new HashSet<QuestionPaperCategory>();

}
```

and a child entity QuestionPaperCategory:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_paper_category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class QuestionPaperCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "question_paper_category_id", columnDefinition = "INT")
    private int questionPaperCategoryId;

    @Column(name = "question_paper_id")
    private int questionPaperId;

    ....
}
```

I want to update just QuestionPaper without updating the child rows (QuestionPaperCategory). Just change the name field.

So, I tried

```
QuestionPaper qPaper = new QuestionPaper();
qPaper.setQuestionPaperId(1)
qPaper.setName("Exam-101")
qPaperRepository.save(qPaper);
```

But it is throwing the following error. I think it's trying to cascade update the child tables. I want to prevent that.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [update question_paper_category set question_paper_id=null where question_paper_id=?]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4042.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.careerfocus.service.QuestionPaperService.addQuestionPaper(QuestionPaperService.java:48)
    at com.careerfocus.service.QuestionPaperService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$79c9ab69.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
    at com.careerfocus.service.QuestionPaperService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f83c70d.addQuestionPaper(<generated>)
    at com.careerfocus.controller.QuestionPaperController.editQuestionPaper(QuestionPaperController.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'question_paper_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1162)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1773)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:958)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:110)
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'question_paper_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1751)
    ... 115 common frames omitted
```

It shows this query in the error.[update question_paper_category set question_paper_id=null where question_paper_id=?]

Why is it trying to update question_paper_category when I've not set in in QuestionPaper

Comment: Can't you get your entity first and then change fields and save?

Comment: OR, you can update it by hql query in your repository, if you want to update only one field

Comment: there're more than 1 fields that I want to update. I only posted just one in my question for readability

Comment: I dont understand your first comment. Please explain

Comment: first you use `findOne(id)` method. Then update all your fields you want on this entity and use method `save(T entity)`

Comment: there're too many cascade tables. Isn't it unnecessary work to fetch them all just to update one table?

Comment: You are still using lazy loading. This will not fetch all your related entities, but will save the connection between - which will not occurs when you try to create new object with same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating new object, you have two ways of updating entities. First - fetch your entity, update fields and save:

```
QuestionPaper qPaper = qPaperRepository.findOne(1);
qPaper.setName("Exam-101")
qPaperRepository.save(qPaper);
```

In this you will update only fields you want, other fields will be unaffected. Notice, that if you are using lazy loading you will not fetch all related entities.

Second is to create update by repository without fetching entity:

```
@Modyfing
@Query("update QuestionPaper qp set qp.name= ?2 where qp.questionPaperId = ?1")
void updateName(String id, String name);
```

Of course, if you want to update more fields you can put more parameters into your query.

Comment: BTW. if you want to update your entity you still have to check if it exists, so you check if repository is returning something with that id

Answer (score 0):

In the **QuestionPaper.java**, you can config the value of the cascade attribute about the **@OneToMany**,and delete the annotation of  @**JoinColumn**(name = "question_paper_id")  what should be used in the @ManyToOne.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_paper")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class QuestionPaper {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "question_paper_id", columnDefinition = "INT")
private int questionPaperId;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="questionPaper", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "question_paper_id")
//    @OrderBy("order")
private Set<QuestionPaperCategory> questionPaperCategorys = new HashSet<QuestionPaperCategory>();
}
```

QuestionPaperCategory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_paper_category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class QuestionPaperCategory {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "question_paper_category_id", columnDefinition = "INT")
private int questionPaperCategoryId;

//    @Column(name = "question_paper_id")
//    private int questionPaperId;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private QuestionPaper questionPaper;
...
}
```

the message at the console:
[image]

the message in th db:
[image]

I have the test. It works.

Comment: I've a uni directional mapping. There's no questionPaper in QuestionPaperCategory

Comment: I've a bi-directional mapping and test it. It works. hoping this helps and trying to improve my Englinsh.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root of the problem is you have an auto generated Id, but you are creating a new instance and manually specifying it.

Try leaving your Id null and let the auto generation do it's thing.

Alternatively if you are trying to update an existing record, retrieve the record first then edit it. There will be no need to set the Id for this approach because it will already be in the retrieved object.

Additionally your joining column should be specified in your @OneToMany.

Comment: he can't set id null, because he want to UPDATE existing entity.